# Access contacts that have been delegated

Tags: google-contacts-api

Within a GSuite Business Domain, how do I access contacts that have been delegated. For instance using the Google People API (https://people.googleapis.com/v1).

Delegated contacts do not have a specific group of their own, which might enable further access (https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups)

Comment: You may want to check on this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-contacts-api/ZVxCtoIBmnY). It was stated that if you are a domain admin and the contacts you want to retrieve belong to a user of your domain, you can use [2-Legged OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to request the contacts by "impersonating" the user.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you abielita for your interest in my issue! 2-Legged oAuth helps but it requires to "crawl" the contacts of each user that has delegated his/her contacts. Realizing this made me rethink my question. Google justly does not allow to pull delegated contacts. Delegating shouldn't include the consent to expose  your contacts to others then the recipient of the delegation. Getting the contacts directly from the users involved via 2 or 3 way oAuth will be my path. I will close the question.